# YouTube (injected) video ends callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, youtube, youtube-api

I inject YouTube iframe to a div in document ready and bind it to click:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.video-thumb').click(function(){
        ...
        $('#player').html('<iframe width="761" height="421" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).attr('videoid') + '?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        ...
    }
 }
```

And I want to do a callback when video ends. I have read about [onYouTubePlayerAPIReady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing), but it has to be put outside document ready.

I have tried to load video player by this construction outside document ready:

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '421',
      width: '761',
      videoId: '',
      playerVars: { autoplay: 1, autohide: 1, showinfo: 0 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
```

but I got some issues:

- showinfo:0 didn't work, still got other video thumbnails in the end
- I don't know how to change video id (and reinit the video?)
- more script errors than first method (injecting iframe)

I prefer using first method, but how to create video ends callback? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you loading the iframe via jQuery? Why not just use the API to load it using the `videoId: 'XXXXXX'` option?

Comment: your question title is misleading...you clearly know how to detect when the video ends from that other SO question.http://stackoverflow.com/a/11726088/65387

Comment: @Asherlc videoId is option of onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() which has to be put outside document ready. I need to load video on element click. Is there a way to change videoId and reinit the player? I've tried but no luck.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A working example of the below code is also on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/vPELX/2/).

Some notes:

- Uses the [iframe_api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), not the [javascript_api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)
- The YT.Player constructor is minimal because you are building the iframe yourself.
- The "playerVars" are included as iframe URL parameters.
- The parameter "enablejsapi=1" is set.

#### Example Markup

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<a style="display: block;" class="video-thumb" id="HuGbuEv_3AU" href="#">
    Megadeth: Back In The Day
</a>  
<a style="display: block;" class="video-thumb" id="jac80JB04NQ" href="#">
    Judas Priest: Metal Gods
</a> 
<a style="display: block;" class="video-thumb" id="_r0n9Dv6XnY" href="#">
    Baltimora: Tarzan Boy
</a>   

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="log">--Logging enabled--</div>
```

#### The JavaScript

```
function log(msg) {
    jQuery('#log').prepend(msg + '<br/>');
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
            log('Video has ended.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
            log('Video is playing.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
            log('Video is paused.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
            log('Video is buffering.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
            log('Video is cued.');
            break;
        default:
            log('Unrecognized state.');
            break;
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.video-thumb').click(function() {

        var vidId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#container').html('<iframe id="player_'+vidId+
            '" width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+
            vidId+'?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0" '+
            'frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

        new YT.Player('player_'+vidId, {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, I think I will use this example for my project as well :-) thank you for posting.

Comment: Hey.. do you know something like this for `vimeo`?

Comment: Looks like the JSFiddle example I linked to no longer works.  JSFiddle doesn't correctly load the `YT` global var provided by the `iframe` API.  It will still work in your own application, though.