# onYouTubePlayerReady callback not triggering

Tags: javascript, youtube, callback

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted)

calling an embed with the url http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1 should trigger the callback onYouTubePlayerReady() when the video is ready. I have tried to achive this like this:

```
<body>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="56.25"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerID){
    console.log(playerID);
    console.log('working');
    alert('working');
}
```

But the callback isn't triggered, see js-fiddle: what am i doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/B85p5/1/

Comment: To test any of these calls, you must have your file running on a webserver, as the Flash player restricts calls between local files and the internet.

Comment: It's likely because it's in an iframe. You want the swobject on this page.

Comment: don't forget allowScriptAccess when you do it

Comment: seems it's duplicate, please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003597/why-isnt-the-youtube-iframe-player-calling-onyoutubeplayerready-when-its-loade

Comment: hi u just want autoplay the video is that wat u need.

Comment: @codebreaker unfortunately, I need an event to trigger when the video has stopped playing.

Comment: hi  u may have gone through this fiddle r not dono but stil this gives callback of youtube video and also this post will help ur cause..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107202/youtube-injected-video-ends-callback ..http://jsfiddle.net/vPELX/2/