# Close fancybox popup when youtube video finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, fancybox

i did a popup with youtube video at page load.

I need that the popup close when the video finish...is it possible to integrate this script?

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen"  />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#yt").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                    'padding'        : 0,
                    'autoScale'      : false,
                    'transitionIn'   : 'none',
                    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
                    'title'          : this.title,
                    'width'          : 880,
                    'height'         : 595,
                    'href'           : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                    'type'           : 'swf',
                    'swf'            : {
                        'wmode'              : 'transparent',
                        'allowfullscreen'    : 'true'
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
    $('#foo').bind('click', function() {
          alert($(this).text());
        });
        $('#foo').trigger('click');
</script>
</head>

<body onload='$("#yt").trigger("click");'>

    <h1>fancybox example</h1>
    <p><a id="yt" title="" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch? v=y0vh14W4iTM&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"></a></p>
```

I report this discussion.

[FancyBox and Youtube API events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880803/fancybox-and-youtube-api-events/23044787?noredirect=1#comment35210006_23044787)

I've not practice with javascript someone can help me?

Comment: Already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107202/youtube-injected-video-ends-callback

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance of the JS player on the page. Then you can target the player state changes. **[HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)** is a link with the info you need.

You can set a script to run when your state is reached that will close your PopUp box.

Answer (score 0):

this is the full script with Fancybox-Youtube-Cookie-Autoclose-Autopopup
just download the images that required in css put them in /fancybox folder in your root and replace with your video id. Really works fully tested...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
// detect mobile devices features
var isTouchSupported = 'ontouchstart' in window,
    isTouchSupportedIE10 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Touch/i) != null;
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    if (!(isTouchSupported || isTouchSupportedIE10)) {
        // this is NOT a mobile device so autoplay     
         event.target.playVideo();
    }
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
        $.fancybox.close();
    }
}
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('welcome_video')) {
        // it hasn't been three days yet
    } else {
        // set cookie to expire in 3 days
        $.cookie('welcome_video', 'true', { expires: 3});
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fancybox.open({
  href: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qm1RjPM9E-g", /*YOUR VIDEO ID*/
            helpers: {
                media: {
                    youtube: {
                        params: {
                            autoplay: 1,
                            rel: 0,
                            // controls: 0,
                            showinfo: 0,
                            autohide: 1,
                        }
                    }
                },
                buttons: {}
            },
            beforeShow: function () {
                var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');
                var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                    events: {
                        onReady: onPlayerReady,
                        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }
        }); // fancybox 
    }); // ready
   } // cookie else ready
}); // function for cookie
} // youtube API ready
</script>
```