# Get Multiple Embedded Youtube Videos to Play Automatically in Sequence

Tags: html, video, youtube, youtube-api

Is there any simple way to have multiple embedded YouTube videos on a page and have them start playing as soon as the page is opened and when the first one finished have the second one start?

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
<object width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk&autoplay=1"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed></object>
<br>
<object width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/NlXTv5Ondgs&autoplay=2"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/NlXTv5Ondgs&autoplay=2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed></object>
```

And it does for the first one but not the second.  I would imagine that I may need to dive into the API.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just add all those videos in a YouTube playlist and embed the playlist on your website. When the first video finishes, the next will start :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the Youtube IFrame API, you can do this easily.

The only part you need to configure here is the array of youtube IDs.  You can retrieve those from the part after the /v/ in the URL (If need be, you can modify the javascript to load URLs instead of IDs.  I just like this way better.

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script>
    /**
     * Put your video IDs in this array
     */
    var videoIDs = [
        'OdT9z-JjtJk',
        'NlXTv5Ondgs'
    ];

    var player, currentVideoId = 0;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            currentVideoId++;
            if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
                player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: okay great! thanks for the help.  now is there any way to have them show in separate players and just play consecutively?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the exact request - do you want them all to display on the screen? and then one to play after another?  So that you can still see the thumbnail/finished screen of each?  If so, that's slightly different - you'd just grab all the IDs of the players as keys of the videoIDs object - and loop through that.  If you need help, please clarify exactly what you'd like - and I'll help out.

Comment: thanks Aaron.  Yes that is precisely what I'd like to do.  I want to have all of the players on the screen and have it loop through them.  The reason for this is so that users can change the video by clicking on a new player.

Comment: You're still not being incredibly clear with the goal.  So you want multiple players on the screen, each to start playing after the previous one has stopped - plus you want click behavior.  Is that behavior that the clicked video stops the other one from playing and then the process takes off from there (ie everything after that one plays again) - or that it stops the automatic playing once and for all?

Comment: Hey, Aaron.. Could you please help me with this? I added my ids and I keep getting back an error. I even tried to upload a single video with a single ID just to see if I was typing the elements of the array incorrectly. It still is not working and renders an error. I love the solution you have here, and if I could get it to work that would be amazing! This is the error I am talking about at my site: floridashuttleservices.com

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using the [YouTube Iframe Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

There are two separate embeds (player1 and player2).  The video autoplays when player1 has loaded, and it starts player2 when it completes.

[Here is the jfiddle if you want to play around with it.](http://jsfiddle.net/45sdT/)

And the code:

```
<div id="player1"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player1;
    var player2;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            videoId: 'OdT9z-JjtJk',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            videoId: 'NlXTv5Ondgs'
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player2.playVideo();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not good at javascript. But I have some similar question before.

[you could referece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing)

judgement the first video is finished then run the second. you could set 2 functions.

```
<div id="player1"></div>
<br>
<object width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" id="player2-param" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350" id="player2-embed"></embed></object>
```

then

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
            if(event.data === 0) {          
                $('#player2-param').attr('value','http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJkautoplay=1');//jquery
                $('#player2-embed').attr('src','http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJkautoplay=1');//jquery

            }
        }
```

hope this could help you and write some nicer code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use youtube API and put autoplay true;make aplaylist on youtube and give link to that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on prev sample code. I have created Basic Vanilla JavaScript Youtube Player- With playlist. Checkout [Youtube Player- With playlist](https://gist.github.com/deepakshrma/17fbb07f220b3d6c127d)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Basic Vanilla  JavaScript Youtube Player- With playlist</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="player" style="width: 480px;height:360px;max-width: 50%;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="youtube" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></div>
    <div class="controls" style="text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;">
        <button style="padding: 10px;width: 100px;background-color: #167AC6;"
                onclick="YouTubePlayer.playPrevious()">Prev
        </button>
        <button style="padding: 10px;width: 100px;background-color: #167AC6;margin-left: 30px;"
                onclick="YouTubePlayer.playNext()">Next
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
    var YouTubePlayer = {
        current: 0,
        player: null,
        /**
         * Tracks ids here...
         */
        videos: [
            'vQMnaDNw5FQ',
            'Dp6lbdoprZ0',
            'OulN7vTDq1I'
        ],
        currentlyPlaying:function(){
            console.info('Current Track id', YouTubePlayer.videos[YouTubePlayer.current]);
            return YouTubePlayer.videos[YouTubePlayer.current];
        },
        playNext: function () {
            YouTubePlayer.increaseTrack()
            if (YouTubePlayer.player) {
                YouTubePlayer.currentlyPlaying();
                YouTubePlayer.player.loadVideoById(YouTubePlayer.videos[YouTubePlayer.current]);
            } else {
                alert('Please Wait! Player is loading');
            }
        },
        playPrevious: function () {
            YouTubePlayer.decreaseTrack()
            if (YouTubePlayer.player) {
                YouTubePlayer.currentlyPlaying();
                YouTubePlayer.player.loadVideoById(YouTubePlayer.videos[YouTubePlayer.current]);
            } else {
                alert('Please Wait! Player is loading');
            }

        },
        increaseTrack: function () {
            YouTubePlayer.current = YouTubePlayer.current + 1;
            if (YouTubePlayer.current >= YouTubePlayer.videos.length) {
                YouTubePlayer.current = 0;
            }
        },
        decreaseTrack: function () {
            YouTubePlayer.current = Math.max(YouTubePlayer.current - 1, 0);
        },
        onReady: function (event) {
            event.target.loadVideoById(YouTubePlayer.videos[YouTubePlayer.current]);
        },
        onStateChange: function (event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                YouTubePlayer.playNext();
            }
        }
    }
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        YouTubePlayer.player = new YT.Player('youtube', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            events: {
                'onReady': YouTubePlayer.onReady,
                'onStateChange': YouTubePlayer.onStateChange
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be complicated, Simply use iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nWHpU7H7Clc?playlist=b6KzNmLMW6o,qWE6g8puu98" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" style="width:900px;height:400px" autoplay="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="player1"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
<input type="button" value="Sustur" id="sus">
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player1;
    var player2;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
            height: '330',
            width: '600',
            videoId: 'mbOuAKqETQY',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
            height: '330',
            width: '600',
            videoId: 'e7mV8driAUQ'
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        document.getElementById("sus").onclick = function() {videoKapat()};
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player2.playVideo();
        }
    }
    

function videoKapat() {
  player2.stopVideo();
  player1.stopVideo();
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).