# Multiple Instances of YouTube Player API on a Single Page

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I've spent the day banging my head on this. I've made some good progress, but this last part has me stuck.

I'm using YouTube's API. I have a listener event configured, and the video autoplays, and autocloses on completion. All of that works great.

What I want to do is have more than one video on a single page (5, actually) assigned by DIV. Is there a way to do that with this code?

```
    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '488',
          width: '800',
          videoId: '49QKXdRTX-A',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {    
if(event.data === 0) {
    $("#player").hide();          
        }    
    }
```

Additionally, it's worth mentioning that I will have a couple of these videos auto-show another DIV on completion, so something like this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {    
if(event.data === 0) {
$("#player").hide();
$("#gallery-main").show();
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I know this isn't an "answer" but you might find value in my other answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199437/get-multiple-embedded-youtube-videos-to-play-automatically-in-sequence/15306649#15306649

Comment: Hmm, really good information, thanks for passing it along! I'll give it a shot.