# How can I redirect to a URL after a HTML video has ended?

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, video

I am trying to redirect to a different URL after a html video has ended. This cannot be using a FLASH player as it won't work on iOS devices. Any help or direction will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myVid = document.getElementById("video1");
    function redirect()
    { 
        if (myVid.ended == true) {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <video id="video1" controls="controls">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body>
```

Comment: `myVid.addEventListener('onended', function(e) { window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; }); `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the id of your video to 'myvid' and here is the solution

```
video = document.getElementById('myvid');
video.addEventListener('ended',function() {alert('video is ended');       
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';})
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7MtFF/4/)

Comment: I am still a little stuck. The video did not redirect after it was finished playing.

Comment: @CAI_Innovator let me know for this

Comment: @CAI_Innovator on jsfiddle can not redirect but ir works fine i have tested it

Comment: @K3mel31 Thank you I got it to work. It was a matter of moving the script out of the head tag and into the body tag. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

use window.location.replace('http://www.google.com'); so user dosnt get stuck in back button loops

```
<script>
    var video1 = document.getElementsByTagName('video1')[0];

    video1.onended = function(e) {
        window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
 document.getElementById('video-id').addEventListener('ended',function(){
     window.location.href = 'http://www.your-url.com';
 },false);
```

jQuery:

```
  $("#video-id").on("ended", function() {
       window.location.href = 'http://www.your-url.com';
    });
```

Youtube:

[How to detect when a youtube video finishes playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing)

Comment: this code is perfectly working on chrome and edge but why it is not working on firefox???

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
<script>
  function videoEnded() {
      location.href="https://www.google.com";
   }
</script>

<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay onended="videoEnded()">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```