# How can I redirect to home page after video stops

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, cincopa

I am using Cincopa to embed my video into my website.  The page that it is embedded in is hidden and navigation is removed.  So I would like everyone to be redirected to the home page once the video is finished.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="cp_widget_55a42f1b-6e51-4738-87f9-eaf52dc6a826">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cpo = [];
    cpo["_object"] = "cp_widget_55a42f1b-6e51-4738-87f9-eaf52dc6a826";
    cpo["_fid"] = "AsBAj2M3MQOr";
    var _cpmp = _cpmp || [];
    _cpmp.push(cpo);
    (function() {
        var cp = document.createElement("script");
        cp.type = "text/javascript";
        cp.async = true;
        cp.src = "//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime/libasync.js";
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Powered by Cincopa <a href='http://www.cincopa.com/video-hosting'>Video Hosting for Business</a> solution.<span>Test</span><span>bitrate</span><span> 39961 kb/s</span><span>height</span><span> 1080</span><span>duration</span><span> 00:02:35.31</span><span>lat</span>:<span> +33.2269</span><span>long</span>:<span> 21-96.93</span><span>fps</span><span> 59.94</span><span>width</span><span> 1920</span><span>originaldate</span><span> 2015-06-06 19:08:58</span>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Hey @Christopher Moore did you have any luck with this?

Comment: "***This question has not received enough attention.***" because it already has many possible duplicates: [How can I redirect to a URL after a HTML video has ended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008778/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-url-after-a-html-video-has-ended) and [Redirect html5 video after play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421471/redirect-html5-video-after-play)

Comment: any [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) ? just paste the whole code there

Answer (score 8):

Cincopa embeds a video HTML tag, you have to add an event as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes)

Well, right now I'm not quite in the mood to make a complete test, so I'll just suggest a workaround which you will need to adapt.

In order to give you the exact code, I need to know:

1. What CMS are you using?
2. Can you add an id or a class to your video tag with cincopa?
3. Are you including jQuery?

Then you'll have to add this lines in the bottom of your script:

```
//Wait until the page is entirely loaded, and so you can access the rendered video tag (you'll need jQuery)
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    function goHomeYouAreDrunk(e) {
        window.location.href = "http://url.to.your.home.page";
    }
    //I'm supposing that your video is the sole video tag in your page, if it's not, you'll have to get it by its id or class
    document.find('video').addEventListener('ended',goHomeYouArDrunk,false);
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you.  I guess maybe I am not quite understanding how to exactly do this or even where this needs to be placed in the code.  Could you perhaps help me out here.

Comment: I'm not at home, but I'll try to edit the answer as soon as I come back

Comment: I would greatly appreciate your help.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, it's not in my top ten answers, but at least this should point you in the right direction. I'll complete it tomorrow when I'm sober...

Comment: Luis, I appreciate your help.  I am using WIX and I can edit the CSS in Cincopa.  I am not using jquery that I am aware of.

CSS code is to long to paste in here.

Comment: Honestly , I didn't find the time to do it today. Did you try to add the code I shown you to the script you posted? Just incluye Jquery and give it à try. In any case, I'la give it à look tomarnos at 15h Gmt+1

Comment: There's a typo in your example, it's missing a "e" in `goHomeYouAreDrunk`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, that would be via an event listener on the `<audio>` or `<video>` element.

**How to add Event Listeners | W3Schools :**  https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

But a way I'd do it with Javascript just to be sure is:

```
// The interval clocks every .1 second(s).
setInterval(function() {
    // If the element's current playback time is the playback duration (has reached the end).
    if (audioElement.currentTime == audioElement.duration)
        doSomething()
}, 100)
```

Although if you are wary about performance and don't want to use a `setInterval()` function, then stick with adding an event to the element.

By the way, to re-direct to another page, use the Javascript function `location.assign("https://www.example.com.")`.

Answer (score 1):

This code has been tested in https://www.cincopa.com/:

```
document.getElementById("video_iframe_id_in_your_page")
    .contentWindow
    .document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]
    .addEventListener("ended", function(args){
        window.open("/", "_top");
    });
```

wish can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the home page by setting `window.location="/"`

I'm not sure how you're checking if the video has ended, you can add a listener like this.

Upon completion, you can call a handler function to redirect the user to the homepage.

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',redirectToHomePage,false);

redirectToHomePage(){
   window.location = "/";
}
```