# How do i Know The Video Has Been Completely Seen in YouTube in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, video, youtube

I have placed a hyperlink (`href`) in my page and after clicking it will redirect to YouTube page and below to `href` i have placed a button , it has to enable after his video has been completed in YouTube . Now , how can I know that he has Completely seen the Video in the YouTube (to enable button) using Java .

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible... you might need to enable the button once the hyperlink is clicked or put a message asking users to press button after completing the video as per your requirment.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing

Comment: Actually im Redirecting by Using href thats why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing , its not helping me - akil mittal

Comment: i wanna make validation for it , after he completes one Video  ill save in my DB that video : 1 has completed and after that Video : 2 completed. then i will enable the button by Checking From DB that he has Completed 2 of the Training Video's .  help reg This .