# YouTube API starts two videos in the same time

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I have two videos that are controlled with YouTube api, everything works fine excepting that when the page loads the first video starts (this is normal) but on the same time you can hear the sound of the second video (this must start after first video ends or is manually closed) which can be better heard if you pause the first video...does anyone has a solution for this?

I think that this happens because both video are calling the `onReady` event.

It is a must to start the second video automatically when the first one ended or was closed.

```
<style>
   .second-video {
      display: none;
   }
</style>

<div class="video-site">
  <div class="first-video">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div id="player"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-video">
    <div id="player2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
  // create youtube player
  var player;
  var player2;

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'qCDxEif_9js',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '43jHG-yH9Gc',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // autoplay video
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    $('.close').click(function(){
      $('.first-video').hide(3000);
      event.target.stopVideo();
      $('.second-video').fadeIn();
    });
  }

  // when video ends
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {
      $('.first-video').hide(3000);
      $('.second-video').fadeIn();
    }
  }

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjrx8uyz/

Comment: Yes both players fire onPlayerReady and play the video

Comment: But how can I change this to make the second video starts only after first video ended or has been manually closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yjrx8uyz/3/

Basically you have to check which player has fired the ready event and closing event.

```
if(event.target == player)
```

Ref : [How to detect when a youtube video finishes playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing)

Comment: The second video needs to start automatically when first video ended or is closed

Comment: Another important thing is that the second video must be initially hidden.

Comment: Just use  `$('.second-video').hide();` at the start of script .. or on document ready of jquery