# Javascript - Check if the site is playing iframe audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I would like to know how can I check if the site is playing the audio. I have tried this, but it doesnt seem to work for me:
HTML:

```
<iframe width="500px" height="300px" id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gPDcwjJ8pLg"></iframe>
```

And my JS:

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('player');

myAudio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
  myAudio.currentTime = 0;
  alert("ended");
});
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your YouTube link is an `<iframe>` element; it has no concept of an `ended` event. Only the `<audio>` and `<video>` elements have such an event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a youtube video finishes playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing)

Comment: No, I want to check if the site is playing any audio, not if the audio finishes playing.

Comment: @ObsidianAge ok, I understand that now. So do you have any idea how can i check if the iframe audio is playing on the site?

Comment: Rename your questions as  `any idea how can i check if the iframe audio is playing` this is interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your website and control the player using JavaScript.

Comment: Good, but I would rather like to have iframe as HTML element and not as getting called by the API. Can I control the iframe element just by the javascript?