# Button disable until youtube video ends- react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, youtube, disable

I'm fairly new to react typescript. I want my video to finish and only then will the continue button be abled.
I found how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing) in javascript but for some reason it doesn't work for react typescript.
This is my code so far:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

function timeout(delay: number) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, delay));
}

export function Video() {
    return (
        <Container className="p-3">
    <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">
      <h4 className="alert-heading"></h4>
      <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <big> <b>  Please watch the video </b> </big>
        <br />
      </p>
      <iframe
        title={"video"}
        width={"560"}
        height={"315"}
        style={{
          marginLeft: "auto",
          marginRight: "auto",
          marginBottom: "40px",
          display: "block",
        }}
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iw5lP63fUxY?autoplay=1&controls=0"
        frameBorder={"0"}
        allow={
          "accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        }
        allowFullScreen
          />
          <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <Link to="/A">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-info">
               Continue
      </button>
      </Link>
        </p>
            </div>
        </Container>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Expecially the "onBufferEnd" callback.

`<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' onBufferEnd={()=>setCanContinue(true)} />`

and the "Continue" button:

`const [canContinue,setCanContinue] = useState(false)`

`<button type="button" {canContinue ? "" : "disabled"} className="btn btn-info">`

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for your quick answer- it did disable the button, but does not enable it when the video finishes. we wrote the following: export function Video() {
    const [CanContinue, setCanContinue] = useState(false); and then: <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" disabled={CanContinue}>
    Continue
    </button>

Comment: Did you use ReactPlayer with onBufferEnd?

Comment: Yes we did, exactly like you suggested. It did disable the button once the video started playing, but when the video finished it stayed disabled, not allowing us to continue.